# OperationContext.Current not correct when moving staging to production in Azure

Tags: .net, wcf, azure, operationcontext

We have an Azure WCF service that uses OperationContext to get the calling uri like this:

> Dim originalUri As String =
>   OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.OriginalString

This was working until we recently made a change to the site. We published the change to the staging slot in Azure, and verified the site was working as expected in staging.

After moving the staging version to production in Azure we noticed that the originalUri was now returning the staging uri. originalUri is now returning http://www.example-staging.com when it should be returning http://www.example.com

Why would this happen? Is there a configuration that needs to be changed in Azure when moving from staging to production?

Comment: Try restarting your site.  You're probably getting a value stored in the process's memory that wasn't updated when you swapped the environments.

Comment: I'll try this and report what happens.

Comment: @RickRainey - Restarting fixed the issue. You can post it as an answer and I can accept it if you want credit.